# Investing in halal company that is partnered with company planning to add leverage trading (involves interest) in the future

Tags: riba, money, business, finance, investment

Salam all, I have invested in a cryptocurrency ICO (like an IPO for cryptocurrencies/crowdsale) after researching into it to find any sort of haram connections or actions taking place by the company. I found nothing at the time but today I came across it being partnered with another ICO that is looking to implement leverage trading in the future into their platform. Is it haram to purchase tokens and invest in this company? Jazak Allah for your time.

Comment: First of all cryptocurrency itself is not considered as legal. And it would be better to not invest in a company which does haram activity, but involvement of interest doesn't make things haram, it varies by country, if the country is possessed by a muslim king and people follow the sharia law then its haram.